# How to use useRef hook and getClientBoundingRect with React and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-functional-component

everyone.

I need to the get sizes of my functional component on React. This project are using Typescript, so I need type functions and other things. I trying with `useRef()` hook like this:

```js
function MyComponent (): JSX.Element {
  const targetREf = useRef<HTMLDivElement>() // I'm typing useRef like this.
  const [boxHeight, setBoxHeight] = useState()

  useLayoutEffect((): void => {
    setBoxHeight(targetRef.current && targetRef.current.getClientBoundingRect())
  }, [targetRef.current])
}
```

The problem is with `getClientBoundingRect()`.

Typescript says: `Property 'getClientBoundingRect' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'.`

How can I should typing my `useRef()` to use `getClientBoundingReact`?

**I'm using React 16.8.6 and Typescript 3.4.5.**

Thanks!

Comment: `targetREf` is not a `HTMLDivElement`, `targetREf.current` is. You should use something like `{ current: HTMLDivElement }` or probably better to use `{ current: Element }`.

Comment: and side note, `useRef` is to keep value _between_ renders(just like `useState` but when changing value does not trigger re-render). You don't need that feature, so you may init `const targetREf = React.createRef();` just in sake of making intention clear,

Answer (score 1):

I think you misspelled the name of the function. It is called:

getBoundingClientRect not getClientBoundingReact.

Hope this helps.